# How to do friendly URLs work with slashes in the end?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, friendly-url, seo

My .htaccess file has the current setting:

```
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

When I enter mydomain.com/file it's ok, but when I access mydomain.com/file/ I get error 500.

There's no folder called "file", this problem appears with any path.

Comment: Hi, you had an nginx question: "I need turn domain.com/?q=es in domain.com/es". The page is gone, but here is an answer: if ( $args ~ q=(..) ) { set $dom $1; rewrite (.*) /$dom; break;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding -MultiViews to your Options. If it still breaks, look at the apache error_log, you'll get the full explaination of what's going wrong.